# Kubernetes pod DNS resolution

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

The /etc/resolv.conf in my containers show "default.svc.cluster.local", if I do an nslookup on one of my services, it shows {servicename}.default.svc.cluster.local. I was wondering what the 'svc' in the search path was referring to as I am doing an nslookup on the servicename already. I.e. is it not duplicated?

For the "cluster.local" part, how do you find the name of your cluster? I would like to know so that I can define it in my Helm template.

Answer (score 2):

`cluster.local` is defined in a configMap `coredns` in kube-system namespace.

```
kubectl get cm coredns -n kube-system -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
```

Check the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/) if you want to customize it.

Comment: Ah, great thanks! Do you know what the "svc" in "{servicename}.default.svc.cluster.local" means if {servicename} is at the start?